# django form aren't saving after added queryset filter in form __init__ method

Tags: python, django

I've filtered a field queryset from my django form and now suddenly in html page when i hit submit it doesn't save anymore but if i comment the method, I can save again. Any help is much appreciated below is my code

model :

```
class Model_A(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    project_manager = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project_manager', null=True,
                                        blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name
```

form.py :

```
class EditProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    prefix = 'edit_form'
    class Meta:
        model = Model_A
        fields = '__all__'    

    #Save failed after adding this method
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['project_manager'].queryset = Employee.objects.filter(department__in=[18, 19, 20]).exclude(employment_status=6)
```

view.py :

```
def project_setting(request, project_id):
    form = EditProjectForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=selected_project, prefix='settings')
    if form.is_valid():
        inst = form.save(commit=False)
        inst.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/projects/{}/setting'.format(project_id))
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, '/projects/setting.html', context=context)
```

Comment: You've added the parameter, but you don't seem to be passing it in when you instantiate the form

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman, may I know how can I solve this

Comment: By passing in the user argument.

Comment: @DanielRoseman sorry I don't mean to be too depending, but where can I pass the user args? is it on the __init__ method__ in form or  during form validation in view, would appreaciated it a lot if you can show me an example or django document thanks. I'm new in programming

Comment: First explain why you added that user parameter to the method.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added the perimeter, because I wanted only user from those 3 particular user to be able to be assign as project manager

Comment: But you changed the signature to accept `user`. **Why?** You are not using it and you are not passing it in.

Answer (score -2):

**Update :**

Found the solution, instead of filter the queryset from form.py, just query it in view.py with this line :

```
form.fields['project_manager'].queryset = Employee.objects.filter(department__in=[18, 19, 20]).exclude(employment_status=6)
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the important problem that Daniel brought up in the comments: you've added a `user` parameter to `__init__`, but you're not passing any user in to the constructor, therefore you've destroyed the form's request reference, and, consequently, destroyed a lot of the form's functionality. (Sometimes it's a shame Python doesn't have static typing.)